# How to make enemy face player in top down unity

Tags: game-development

I have researched a lot on this topic but I can never find a correct solution. I have a enemy that is in a red diamond shape and I want to have the points always facing the player. I have successfully made them move toward the player but haven't got them to face it. Below is my code for my enemy movement and the image of my enemy.

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;


public class EnemyMovement : MonoBehaviour
{
    [SerializeField] private float _speed = 9;
    private Transform _target;
    void Awake()
    {
        _target = GameObject.FindGameObjectWithTag("Player").transform;
    }
    void Update()
    {
        transform.position = Vector3.MoveTowards(transform.position, _target.position, _speed * Time.deltaTime);
    }
}
```

[here is a link to the photo of my enemy sprite](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Lt3O5.png)

Answer (score 0):

Good day!

Try looking into: https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Transform.LookAt.html
which would probably be the easiest and best solution, but there are also other ways, like: https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Quaternion.SetLookRotation.html which you can use to set the enemy to always look at the player.

I would probably use LookAt

I hope this helps and good luck with your coding

Comment: I am using the LookAt, but now when the enemies spawn I only see a flicker of them and then they disappear.

Comment: It might be possible that your enemies don't have z as the forward axis. By default, LookAt uses Y as an upward axis for reference to get the forward axis. LookAt has a second parameter where you can define which axis will be the upwards axis. You can see an example of this second parameter in use on the documentation page.

Comment: Thank you so much, now I can see that it is changing the z axis but it is also changing the x and y and those need to to stay 0 in order for you to see the enemies. Is there a way to set the enemies rotation to zero in a script?

Comment: It might be changing the other axis's, because your player might not be at the same level as the enemies. For example: If your player is 2m below the enemy, then the enemy will look in the players direction, but will also look down towards the player. What you could do to fix this is: Restrict the LookAt to not use the y axis. It might look something like this: 
transform.LookAt( new Vector3(_target.position.x, transform.position.y, _target.position.z) );
Not sure if the aforementioned will work, but I hope so